Что за ЯП .NET?
Я новичок в программировании, натыкаюсь везде на какой-то язык .NET. Что обычно имеется в виду под .NET? C# или сайт какой-то с расширением .NET? Всегда говорят именно НЕ "технология" .NET, а "язык программирования№ .NET. Что это может быть, помогите пожалуйста.

.NET это платформа, на которой работает C#. Поверх .NET также работают другие языки, такие как F#, Visual Basic .NET, Iron Python и прочие

Дот.Нет - это так называемая платформа. От Майрософта. Впрочем есть реализация не только от Майкрософта, но это не важно. В эту платформу как и в любую другую включено много чего. Это например языки программирования и исполняющие среды. И всякие программки всё это обслуживающие. И суть снова не в этом. Суть в Майкрософте. Майкрософт всё делает так лениво, что никогда [или почти никогда] ничего не меняет. А зачем? Майкрософт обычно дописывает поверх уже существующего.

Отсюда грандиозные выводы: Пока жив Майкрософт [а он разумеется - вечен], и будет жить Дот.Нет. Т.е. Дот.Нет - вечен. И второе - Дот.Нет почти не изменяется. Т.е. не надо куда то бежать скакать что бы успевать за какими то изменениями в Дот.Нете. Всё всегда очень лениво. Но существует ровно одна проблема. Порог входа в Дот.Нет весьма высок.
